# How to proove that all elements in a list are smaller than a given element in coq

Tags: coq, proof

I have a list  `20 :: 75 :: 123 :: 12 :: nil` and I would like to prove that all elements in the list are greater or equal than `10`.

So what I did is that I created a Fixpoint to extract the min of the list, so here `12` and then I would like to use it to conclude.

So I am basically stuck with the following goal:

`INR 10 <= nth i (20 :: 75 :: 123 :: 12 :: nil) default_value`

I do not really see what tactics to apply or how to use the Fixpoint I created to conclude that given the smallest element in the list is greater that `10` then so are all elements in the list.

EDIT

I now also have the subgoal `10 <= 12` . This seems trivial but I don't find a tactic to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

These numerical goals can be dealt with by computation. In your specific case, you can do:

```
Definition l := 20 :: 75 :: 123 :: 12 :: nil.

Definition gt_10 := foldr (fun n b => b && (n >= 10)) true l.

Eval cbv in gt_10.
```

Comment: I think his list contains elements from R.  (because of his use of `INR`)

Comment: I'm using ssreflect, and I understand there is some (partial) support for reals and real analysis, although I've never used them. Ordered rings would work fine, IIUC, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to do this kind of proof, and I
don't understand why it the numbers have to be in type `R`.

Here is a solution that works even if the numbers are in `R`, you need to limit the index to be below the length of the list.

```
Require Import List Reals Lra Lia.

Open Scope R_scope.

Definition l := 20 :: 75 :: 123 :: 12 :: nil.

Lemma toto : forall i, (i < length l)%nat -> 10 <= nth i l 0.
Proof.
intros i.
unfold l.
repeat (destruct i as [ | i];[ simpl; intros; lra | try (simpl; intros; lia); simpl]).
Qed.
```

You can make `l` be a list of hundreds of elements (on my old computer, it take 40 seconds for a list of 300 elements), it will still work.  If the list has a few thousands elements, you may
have problems of stack overflow, out of memory, or the computation taking too long.

If instead you have numbers in the types `nat`, `positive`, `Z`, or `Q`, it is probably better to write some code that checks all elements as suggested by Pierre Jouvelot, together with a theorem that links the code and the property you want to establish.